# Why won't "angleString" update in Animated rotate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component, react-animated

I'm trying to create a component on my screen, where the user is able to use their finger to rotate the componnent around its center. I  have been able to get the angle and consistently update it (verified through console.log), but the value is not being passed rotate under Animated.view.

Here is my code:

```
class Spinner extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.angleCalculation = this.angleCalculation.bind(this);
   this.state = {
     angleString: '0deg'
   }
 }

 angleCalculation(x,y){

  xValue = x - 50
  yValue = (y * -1) + 150
  angle = Math.atan(yValue/xValue) * (180/Math.PI)

  this.state.angleString = angle + 'deg'

  console.log(this.state.angleString)

 }

 render() {


  return(

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Animated.View
      style={styles.box, {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width:100,
        height:300,
        transform:[{ rotate: this.state.angleString
        }]
      }}
      onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => true}
      onResponderGrant={(evt) => {this.angleCalculation(evt.nativeEvent.locationX,evt.nativeEvent.locationY)}}
      onResponderMove={(evt) => {this.angleCalculation(evt.nativeEvent.locationX,evt.nativeEvent.locationY)}}
      onResponderRelease={(evt) => {this.angleCalculation(evt.nativeEvent.locationX,evt.nativeEvent.locationY)}}          
    />
  </View>
)
}
}
```

The console.log consistently updates  as I moved my finger in a circular fashion. And it does so  in  the angleString form that I want. In my this.state, I set an initial value of '0 deg' but I am not sure why it is updating under 'rotate'.

What can I do to make it update in real-time? So the rotate accepts the updated values and follows along with the user's finger?

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Comment: You need to use an Animated.Value() to manage this.state.angleString. Taking advantage of React Native animations requires an animated value applied to an animated view. The current code has an animated view without a corresponding animated value. That's why you're not seeing an update in your UI. This assumes all of the responder code is correct. The built-in React Native Animated/gesture API are fine - the community overall has largely moved to usage of react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated for gesture based animation in lieu of the built-ins.

Comment: Change this.state.angleString = angle + 'deg'   to  this.setState({ angleString : angle + 'deg' }).
Note: this is not the best practice. Make use of Animated Events.